# Modelagem de domínio - Formas de pagamento

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, modelagem, ddd

Eu estou modelando a parte de vendas do meu sistema e me deparei com a seguinte situação.
Eu criei um cadastro de formas de pagamento e a forma de pagamento **DINHEIRO** é padrão e não pode ser alterada, excluída, etc. Eu utilizo essa forma de pagamento na abertura de caixa por exemplo. Eu crio essa forma de pagamento na instalação da aplicação.

O sistema permite ao usuário criar novas formas de pagamento de acordo com a necessidade.
Essas novas formas de pagamento podem ser alteradas.

Como eu devo tratar essa situação?

Devo adicionar uma propriedade na classe FormaPagamento que habilita a classe a ser excluída e alterada?

```java
class FormaPagamento {
   private Boolean podeSerAlterado;
}
```

Devo fazer uma verificação sempre que for feita uma operação e se for **DINHEIRO** proibir a operação?

Devo remover as opções de alteração de qualquer forma de pagamento e apenas permitir que sejam criados novas formas de pagamento? Tendo a opção de ativar e desativar formas de pagamento.

```java
class FormaPagamento {
   private Boolean ativo;
}
```

**[ EDITADO ]**

Esse é meu diagrama de classes para formas de pagamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quando o usuário cadastra a forma de pagamento eu exibo as opções para que ele cadastre quais as condições de pagamento ele quer disponibilizar, tipo **2 x sem juros no cartão VISA** seria uma condição com 2 parcelas, 30 dias de recorrência e primeira parcela em 30 dias.

No caso da forma de pagamento **DINHEIRO** eu tenho uma condição padrão que é À Vista, porém o usuário pode querer cadastrar uma nova condição para pagamento em **DINHEIRO**. Por isso mantive essa forma de pagamento no cadastro e não hardcoded.

Comment: Não sei se deveria ser conhecimento da própria forma de pagamento o fato dela poder ser alterada ou não. Acredito que a criação de um serviço responsável por realizar a modificação de formas de pagamento seria uma forma mais desacoplada de resolver isso. Esse serviço verificaria qual forma de pagamento está sendo modificada e falharia caso fosse uma forma que não deve ser modificada. Isso poderia ser uma regra hardcoded na sua aplicação.

Comment: É uma alternativa. Eu não havia considerado essa opção, mas no caso eu só posso realizar esse trabalho no service se considerar isso uma regra da aplicação e não do domínio correto?

Comment: Boa colocação; de certa forma esse conhecimento faz parte do domínio em si é talvez retirar essa responsabilidade dele possa gerar problemas em como as interações com o domínio acontecem. Confesso que não sei exatamente qual padrão as práticas de DDD advogam nesse caso, mas vou dar uma pesquisada pois achei um problema interessante.

Comment: Sim é um problema interessante e que inclusive ocorre em outras partes do sistema, no caso algumas contas do plano de contas também não podem ser alteradas. Porém isso só é um problema porque eu referencio tais objetos pela descrição. No caso da forma de pagamento DINHEIRO, eu busco ela no repositório pela descrição repositorioFormasPagamento.findByDescricao('DINHEIRO') ... por isso não posso permitir que se altere a descrição.

Comment: Nem tudo na vida é cadastro. Há tipos de entidades que existem apenas no código e não no banco de dados. Se a regra de negócio é trivial, deixe o cadastro no banco e não se preocupe em impedir o cliente de excluir "dinheiro" - é só ele cadastrar de novo. Se o sistema é mais complexo, cada forma de pagamento tem comportamentos e relacionamentos exclusivos que não podem ser definidos apenas por seus atributos no banco, nestes casos a entidade é hard coded e não está cadastrada no banco (eventualmente alguns dos seus atributos são cadastrados, mas não a entidade em si).

Answer (score 1):

Eu queria comentar ao inves de responder, mas ainda nao tenho pontos suficientes para tal. Desculpe.

Olhando do ponto de vista apenas da Orientacao a Objeto, o problema me parece ser um caso simples de heranca. Dinheiro, Cheque, Cartao, Boleto, etc, sao especializacoes da classe MeioPagamento.

Nao entendo bem o que voce diz por "criar uma forma de pagamento". Nao conheco seu negocio e posso estar enganado, mas da minha limitada otica me parece que ha um numero pequeno de possibilidades para formas possiveis de pagamento, por isso nao consigo ver sentido em delegar ao usuario o cadastro desses objetos.

Concordo com Fuad quando ele diz "Não sei se deveria ser conhecimento da própria forma de pagamento o fato dela poder ser alterada ou não." O ponto chave eh discernir quando a regra eh de negocio e quando a regra eh petrea. Se voce estiver lidando com regras petreas (por exemplo, CPFs sao compostos somente por digitos), entao faz sentido que o proprio objeto conheca a regra, caso contrario isso deve ficar transparente ao objeto.

Pensando em implementacao, o design pattern Strategy me parece uma boa proposicao para resolver esse problema de forma elegante. Acho que vale a pena avaliar o caso.

Comment: Meu raciocínio foi o seguinte. Podem existir diversos meios de pagamento cartão de crédito, de débito, etc. Mas podem existir cartão de crédito mastercard, ticket alimentação, paypal, pagseguro. Então deixei a critério do usuário. Agora olhando de uma outra ótica pode ser então que existam categorias de meios de pagamento que seriam _Dinheiro_, _Cartão de Crédito_, _Cartão de Débito_, _Boleto_, _Transferência Eletrônica_, _Cheque_. E formas de pagamento da categoria cartão de crédito seriam Visa, Mastercard, American Express. Talvez possa ser encarado dessa forma.

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo um ERP para micro e pequenas empresas.